# como podria calcular el 40% de mi variable sin el uso de librerias

Tags: python

cómo podría calcular un percentil del 40%
(sin usar pandas o numpy ) de mi variable salario. Si en este caso quiero hacerlo con n observaciones

esta es la lectura que hice para mi variable salario

```
def salario(n):
   L=[]
   for elem in range(n):
       print("ingrese el salario de la persona:")
       L.append(float(input()))
   return(L)
```

Comment: de la forma tradicional, `40*x/100`

Comment: @Christian lo puedes hacer más sencillo `x*0.4`

Comment: @nadie claro!, aunque esta vez decidí hacerlo implícito y no explícito ;)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios métodos para calcular percentiles `p` de una lista de valores `x`. Este fue el [primero que encontre](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/statistics/percentile-calculator.php):

- Ordenar los valores en orden ascendente.
- Calcular el ranking `r` del percentil `p` como

  r = (p/100) * (n - 1)
- Si `r` es entero, el percentil es

  p = x[r]
- Si `r` no es entero, el percentil se calcula usando `ri` (parte entera) y `rf` (parte decimal):

  p = x[ri] + rf * (x[ri+1] - x[ri])

Expresado en código:

```
def percentil(per, datos):
    # Copiar la lista para no alterarla
    x = datos.copy()
    x.sort()

    n = len(x)
    rank = (per / 100.0) * (n - 1)
    rank_int = int(rank)
    rank_dec = rank % 1

    if rank_dec:
        p = x[rank_int] + rank_dec * (x[rank_int + 1] - x[rank_int])
    else:
        p = x[rank_int]

    return p
```

#### Demo

```
datos = [10, 10, 20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 70]

for r in range(0, 101, 10):
    print(f"Percentil {r}: {percentil(r, datos)}")
```

produce:

```
Percentil 0: 10
Percentil 10: 10.0
Percentil 20: 18.0
Percentil 30: 20.0
Percentil 40: 26.0
Percentil 50: 35.0
Percentil 60: 43.99999999999999
Percentil 70: 53.0
Percentil 80: 62.0
Percentil 90: 70.0
Percentil 100: 70
```